# installing PHP module from Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to configure my AWS Elastic Beanstalk to work with mongo, all I need to do is install the mongo driver for PHP and update the php.ini file

To do this, usually I would ssh into the EC2 and run:

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

But this would require using a custom AMI which isnt the best way to go.

It is better to use config files to install the software required onto the standard AMI.

So to do this, I have done the following:
created directory .ebextensions
created file mongo.config

in it I have put the following:

```
packages: 
pecl: install mongo
```

However upon deployment, I get the following error:

```
"option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
```

and

```
'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

So I am wondering how this config file needs to be laid out in order to install the mongo extension?

I have read the info here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

but I am not quite understanding  how to do this specific task

Help would be appreciated , thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out and thought I would share what I found. Thanks to Hudku (http://blog.hudku.com/2013/02/innocuous-looking-evil-devil.html#elastic-beanstalk.config) for the excellent article:

1) Create myapp.config
2) enter the following into it

```
packages:
    yum:
        dos2unix: []


container_commands:
    01-command:
        command:        rm -rf /myapp/ebextensions

    02-command:
        command:        mkdir -p /myapp/ebextensions

    03-command:
        command:        cp -R .ebextensions/* /myapp/ebextensions/

    04-command:
        command:        dos2unix -k /myapp/ebextensions/mongo.sh

    05-command:
        command:        chmod 700 /myapp/ebextensions/mongo.sh

    06-command:
        command:        bash /myapp/ebextensions/mongo.sh
```

Then create mongo.sh file and put in it something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f /mongostatus.txt ];
then
    pecl install mongo
    echo "mongo extension installed" > /mongostatus.txt
    apachectl restart
fi
```

This will install mongo php extension and restart apache so the install takes affect.

Answer (score 6):

`pecl` is not a valid package manager on Amazon Linux and therefore cannot be used under the `packages` key of an `.ebextensions` config.

To install a PECL package it is enough to add a single command under the `commands` key. To avoid that Beanstalk tries to install the extension twice on follow-up deployments add a PHP console command to the `test` key that checks if the extension is already installed:

```
commands:
  install_mongo_driver:
    command: pecl install mongo
    test: "php -r \"exit(extension_loaded('mongo') ? 1 : 0);\""
```

If the `test` result is `true`, i.e. `exit(0)`, then the `command` gets executed - otherwise not. Please note that a exit code of `0` means "No errors" in a shell context.

See also the description at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands.

Answer (score 1):

I just accomplished the same thing thanks to the answer above, and figured out it can be done with less lines and less files for those interested...

```
# ~/project/.ebextensions/project.config
# Logger messages can be viewed in /var/log/messages

files:
    "/tmp/test.sh":
        content: |
            # This file will be created and can then
            # be executed by a command call below.
            logger TEST FILE CALLED

commands:
    01-command:
        command: logger CALLING TEST FILE; sh /tmp/test.sh;
```